# Entity Types cannot share table | Not actually the same table though

Tags: entity-framework

I have two databases that so happen to have the same table name. Entity is giving me an InvalidOperationException stating "The entity types 'PmsUser' and 'AcctUser' cannot share table 'NGUSERS'...

I created these using a code first approach.

My models for both look something like

```
[Table("NGUSERS")]
public partial class AcctUser
{
    ...
```

and

```
[Table("NGUSERS")]
public partial class PmsUser
{
    ...
```

They each have their own respective connection string to differing databases. What do I need to do to get it to allow the same table name (modifying the Database isn't an option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two ModelBuilder instead of attributes. Then pass the created `DbModel` to the `DbConnection`. Or set the database name in the DbContext. See [Entity Framework Connections and Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592674(v=vs.113).aspx).

This base class helps to register the model builders with the DbContext:

```
public abstract class ModelBuilderBase {

    protected readonly DbModelBuilder ModelBuilder;

    protected ModelBuilderBase(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        ModelBuilder = modelBuilder;
    }

    public abstract void BuildModel();
}
```

ModelBuilder implementation:

```
public class ModelBuilder1 : ModelBuilderBase {

    public ModelBuilder1 (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) : base(modelBuilder)
    { }

    public override void BuildModel() {

        ModelBuilder.Entity<AcctUser>().ToTable("NGUSERS");
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class DbContext1 : DbContext { 
    public DbContext1() : base("Database1") /* set DB name */ { 
    } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var modelBuilders = new List<ModelBuilderBase> {
            new ModelBuilder1(modelBuilder)
        };

        modelBuilders.ToList().ForEach(x => x.BuildModel());
    }
}
```

Create ModelBuilder2 and DbContext2 for the second DB/Table.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with your initial, smaller answer, but the update is very helpful.